# Extract x coordinates from a put it a new column?

Tags: python, pandas, extract, geopandas

I have this column and I want to extract the `x` coordinates in a new column. The problem is that it contains the word `point`.

The actual type is `geoseries` and originates from the `geopandas` library. So I don't know if it has any issues if methods from the pandas library are applied on it.

```
  geo
  POINT (270504.6944782521 4277096.25338444)
  POINT (270838.1885699595 4278145.324786565)
  POINT (270606.3947049045 4277995.041739198)
  POINT (271508.653647932 4278548.893014569)
```

Something like this:  `df['geo'].str.extract('(\d+)').astype(int)`

Answer (score 1):

It has a `.x` attribute that you can use.

```
df.geo.map(lambda val: val.x)
```

Thanks to @joris for the improved result.

> if you are using the latest version of geopandas (0.3.0) you can do `df.geo.x`

Comment: the only issue now is that the last few digits are not included:instead of 270504.6944782521 it gives 270504.694458

Comment: That's only a question of the string represenation, the actual data has the full detail

Comment: @joris is my answer insufficient? I can't see what I'm missing

Comment: The last few digits are not included in each x coordinate in the result in the new column

Comment: @user9936268 I understand that. Can you show me what the result of `dir(x)` where `x` is one of the coordinate objects. This way we can see all the options available

Comment: i don't understand what you mean:the issue is instead of 270504.6944782521 it gives 270504.694458. The last few digits are not included from the first column of x. possibly it has to do with python and how many digits appear?

Comment: Pandas has a default precision of 6 decimal places, so it's just that 6 dp is being **printed**. It will actually be correct if you look at an individual value or perform further calculations. Apologies, this is essentially what @joris said earlier

Comment: Yep, that's what I meant. In addition, if you are using the latest version of geopandas (0.3.0, already released almost a year ago), you can also do `df.geo.x` as a short-cut for the `map` method

Comment: @joris I have updated the answer with your suggestion. Have I done this properly, i.e. attributing the idea to you/give you credit (meta type question)?

Comment: That's fine for sure!